# Syntax operations. What are the operations involved in the pair here?

Tags: questions, syntax, who-whom, transformation

What are the syntactic operations are involved in the following pair?

IT was:

> she talked with him via email?

IT became:

> With whom did she talk via email? syntax

My book shows that syntactic operations are merge, move, verb rising and so on.

Would you please help me. This is one of the practice questions and I have a test tomorrow.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for the English Language Learners site. It might be appropriate for Linguistics - but you will need to show some attempt to answer the question. We will not do your homework for you.

Comment: This is not a homework. It is a practice question. I believe that there is a both, move and merge operation and a did insertion but I am not sure how to show that in tree structure.

Comment: I have no idea what *move, merge, verb rising and so on* mean with respect to English grammar. At least not with respect to anything that would be on topic to this particular site. In order for anybody to answer this, you would need to edit your question to give definitions and examples of those operations (and all of them instead of *and so on*)—and then ask which of those is taking place in your pre and post examples.